# Columna json en mysql

Tags: mysql, json

estoy intentado parsear una columna donde se almacena un string con formato de json, esta columna contiene a su vez N registros mas pequeños que necesito "separar".

Ejemplo : SELECT * FROM lv_rcs

| id | json |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"data":[{"celular":"5555555555","email":"correo@gmail.com","mensaje":"Mensaje de prueba para SMS default","nombre":"JUAN"}]} |

Como pueden observar el campo json es un string con formato Json que a su vez contiene un array de objetos con N usuarios  mi objetivo es llevar la tabla anterior a la siguiente

| id | nombre | telefono | email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | JUAN | 55555555 | correo@gmail.com |
| 2 | PEDRO | 2222222222 | correo@gmail.com |

Este es el json con un formato mas legible

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "celular":"5555555555",
         "email":"correo@gmail.com",
         "mensaje":"Mensaje de prueba para SMS default",
         "nombre":"JUAN"
      },
      {
         "celular":"2222222222",
         "email":"correo@gmail.com",
         "mensaje":"Mensaje de prueba para SMS default",
         "nombre":"PEDRO"
      }
   ]
}
```

He intentado lo siguiente

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json, "$.data[0].celular")   from lv_rcs ;
```

Esto funciona sin embargo como se pueden dar cuenta solo accedo al objeto en la posicion 0 y necestio recorrer todos los objetos para separar sus respectivas columnas

¿Alguna idea?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Asegurate de que tu tabla lv_rcs tiene una campo indice por el cual identificar cada registro, para que luego ese ``id`` lo puedas retornar en tu consulta y de esta manera podrás diferencias un registro de otro, ya con eso podrás leer a través de un For o algún método de iteración.

Comment: Aprecio el comentario sin embargo el dilema es que no puedo usar un lenguaje y si no me equivoco en mysql solo es posible usar ciclos a menos de que uses un procedimeinto almacenado lo cual tampoco puedo hacer jeje  necesito  hacer  esa separacion en un script de  MySql